# Entity Framework query not returning correctly enumerated results

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ienumerable

I have this really strange problem where my entity framework query isn't enumerating correctly.

The SQL Server table I'm using has a table with a Sku field, and the column is "distinct".  It isn't a key, but it doesn't contain any duplicate values.  Using actual SQL with `where`, `distinct` and `group by` cluases I have confirmed this.

However, when I do this:

```
// Not good
foreach(var product in dc.Products)
```

or

```
// Not good
foreach(var product in dc.Products.ToList())
```

or

```
// Not good
foreach(var product in dc.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Sku))
```

the first two objects that are returned **ARE THE SAME!!!**

The third item was technically the second item in the table, but then the fourth item was the first row from the table again!!!

The only solution I have found is to use the Distinct extension method, which shouldn't really do anything in this situation:

```
// Good
foreach(var product in dc.Products.ToList().Distinct())
```

Another weird thing about this is that **the count of the resulting queries is the same!!!**  So whether or not the resulting enumerable has the correct results or duplicates, I always get the number of rows in the actual table!  (No I don't have a limit clause anywhere).

What could possibly cause this!?!?!?

Comment: This seems to be related to keys... the table doesn't have any keys.  Anyone know if EF/LINQ require keys to be there?

Comment: It looks like adding a key fixed the problem, but I'm still curious why this happens with no warning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a Primary Key for the table.

Comment: Indeed, the lack of a primary key skews results